# Network connectivity problems in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, motherboard, hardware-failure

I'm experiencing a quite annoying problem in Windows 10 where I lose my network connection randomly (seemingly). I have tried to update Windows, the network card drivers, reinstalling Windows and changed all kinds of network settings. I have even updated bios if the problem lies in the motherboard but to no use. I need to restart my pc between 1 to 10 times before I get a connection again. I have tried using the ethernet cable in another pc and there it works but right when i plug it in to mine it says it doesn't work. I tought it was a problem with my motherboard (as I have had other problems with it) but then i booted Ubuntu from a USB-stick and it had no problem with accessing the network. To make sure it wasn't just a one of thing I went from Windows to Ubuntu a couple of times but it always worked on Ubuntu and never on Windows.

Motherboard: MSI B550M PRO-VDH WIFI

I really just want clarity if it is my motherboard or Windows or maybe even both thats the problem and if I need to get a new motherboard or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Get a USB to Ethernet Adapter and try that. This will help you get a handle on the issue.

Comment: Since you state Ubuntu works flawlessly, then it certainly is *not* a hardware issue, but Windows configuration. Though you might try an external WiFi dongle workaround, it seems a bit of a kluge to *require* new hardware because of a Windows issue. That said, WiFi adapters are US$10 or so, not expensive.